# Is it possible for me to work at NASA or other research companies as aircraft mechanic?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-structures

I know NASA is huge but is it possible for me to work there or other companies similar to it?  If possible, how?

I currently work at an MRO as aircraft mechanic. My work is mainly on flight controls. The only aircraft that I have experience on is a320 family.

We do some structural works too, knowledgable to SRM.

I'm from Philippines btw.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If NASA advertises for a mechanic and you meet their requirements - including being able to work legally at their location and perhaps needing a security clearance - then you can certainly apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, unless you are a U.S. citizen (dual-citizenship should be ok.) [According to NASA](https://nasajobs.nasa.gov/jobs/noncitizens.htm),

> Other than under extremely rare exceptions, you must be a U.S. citizen in order to work for NASA as a civil service employee.

It's extremely unusual for non-citizens to be able to work in the U.S. in agencies like NASA or the Department of Defense, where there is necessarily lots of equipment and/or information subject to [ITAR controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations) and/or which is [classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classified_information_in_the_United_States). This will generally also be true for contractor positions.

At my present job, we are not allowed to disclose anything more than high-level marketing material regarding products subject to ITAR to anyone who is not a U.S. citizen, for example, even though we don't make weapons or anything like weapons.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm asking the wrong question lol. Is there any area which I can work not in commercial aviation? Field of aviation where revenue is not the priority? Just looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

Boeing, Airbus, Textron Aviation, and more are all major aircraft manufacturers and there are also many other aircraft part manufacturers such as GE. Also just to correct, NASA is not a company and is instead a government agency. Especially around the US, mechanics and pilots in the next 20 years are a major necessity as the frequency of air travel increases. Also, be reminded, working for the biggest companies will be less flexible than smaller ones. Now if there is a mechanic opening at NASA which there most likely is, be not afraid to take it.